# Based Apache Atlas with Hive, where is the metadata stored? in Titan Graph Repository or in RDBMS with Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, metadata, titan, apache-atlas

I have installed Atlas, Hive and Hadoop and configured them correctly.
But I want to know where the metadata is stored after importing metadata?

According some docs of Atlas, it said that the metadata will be stored in Titan graph repository. 
However, according some docs of Hive, it shows that the metadata will be stored in RDBMS such as MySql.

If I install both Atlas and Hive, where the metadata will be stored spcifically?

Answer (score 1):

Though the existing answer is not wrong, I think it is good to point out that the asker seems to be mixing up two kinds of metadata.

1. Hive metadata: This is indeed stored in a relational DB, with MySQL being the default
2. Atlas metadata: This is stored in HBase (Titan was backed by Hbase for older versions?)

An example of Hive metadata is 'what are the columns'

An example of Atlas metdata is 'how did I tag column a'

---

So if you install both Hive and Atlas, there will be two kinds of metadata, and this will be stored in the mentioned spots.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata is stored in HBase database.The HBase database is maintained by Apache Atlas itself.